# Tracing a recursive factorial function in C++?

Tags: c++, recursion, trace

Having trouble with a little exercise,
suppose I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorialFinder(int x) {
    if (x==1) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return x*factorialFinder(x-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << factorialFinder(5) << endl;
}
```

How would you trace this?
For example:

```
Put in 5 into the factorialFinder function.
if (5 == 1) (False, so skip)
returns 5 times factorialFinder(5-1)
this means returns 5 times factorialFinder(4)
this means go back to function
if (4 == 1) (False, so skip)
returns 4 times factorialFinder(4-1)
...etc.
```

Now if you follow my logic, my question is in my last statement

```
returns 4 times factorialFinder(4-1)
```

Does it return 4 or does it return 20 because it multiplies the 5*4 first?

Comment: Question yourself whether it works for `1` or not. For `2`? If it works for any `n`, does it work for `n+1` (ignoring overflows for the time being.

Comment: That one returns 24.  Which gets used in the outermost function which calculates 5 * 24 = 120 and returns that

Comment: maybe you can debug your code from your machine, it's more easy to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generate a trace is to **instrument** the code, adding trace output statements. It can be a good idea to create some support for that. E.g.,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto operator*( int const n, string const& s )
    -> string
{
    string result;
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) { result += s; }
    return result;
}

class Tracer
{
private:
    std::string callspec_;
    std::string result_;

    auto call_level()
        -> int&
    {
        static int the_level;
        return the_level;
    }

    static auto indent() -> string { return ".  "; }

public:
    template< class Value >
    auto result( Value v )
        -> Value
    {
        result_ = to_string( v );
        return v;
    }

    ~Tracer()
    {
        --call_level();
        clog << "<- " << call_level()*indent() << callspec_;
        if( not result_.empty() )
        {
            clog << " returns " << result_;
        }
        clog << endl;
    }

    Tracer( string funcname )
        : callspec_( move( funcname ) )
    {
        clog << "-> " << call_level()*indent() << callspec_ << endl;
        ++call_level();
    }
};

auto factorial( int const x )
    -> int
{
    Tracer trace( "factorial " + to_string( x ) );
    return trace.result( x == 1? 1 : x*factorial( x - 1 ) );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    cout << factorial( 5 ) << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
-> factorial 5
-> .  factorial 4
-> .  .  factorial 3
-> .  .  .  factorial 2
-> .  .  .  .  factorial 1
<- .  .  .  .  factorial 1 returns 1
<- .  .  .  factorial 2 returns 2
<- .  .  factorial 3 returns 6
<- .  factorial 4 returns 24
<- factorial 5 returns 120
120
```

However, just using a **debugger** to execute the code step by step can be just as enlightening with much less work.

Answer (score 2):

For deep understanding how any code works, you can print steps, where application runs

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorialFinder(int x) {
    cout << "f: " << x << endl;
    if (x==1) {
        cout << "return 1" << endl;
        return 1;
    }else{
        const int res = x*factorialFinder(x-1);
        cout << "return " << res << endl;
        return res;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << factorialFinder(5) << endl;
}
```

And output is:

```
f: 5
f: 4
f: 3
f: 2
f: 1
return 1
return 2
return 6
return 24
return 120
120
```